# Is there any way in symfony2.3 version where I can convert all the yaml files in my project into xml?

Tags: php, symfony-2.3

I just started working on symfony2.3 and I just want to know from my experienced symfony2.3 developers that is there any way in symfony2.3 version where I can convert all the yaml files in my project into xml?

Answer (score 1):

http://xmltoyaml.com/

First search in google. I guess this is what you're looking for?

Comment: There I will have to convert all the yml files manually..Is there any way to do the same in symfony?

Comment: I didn't find any bundle to achieve this... I guess the easiest way would be creating a script to do that. Like search all the .yml files, read them, send via get to that website and receive the result and save it into a xml file. A little bit of engineering but would do the trick, I guess.